# Javascript: Mutating "05/01/2013" into "20130501"?

Tags: javascript

So I have a string that represents a date and I need to change the format of it. This is what I have so far:

```
    function myFunction()
    {
    var dateto = "05/01/2013";
    dateto.replace("/", "");
    //now what?
    }
```

It will always originally be in the MM/DD/YYYY format, and I need to change it to a YYYYMMDD format. I'm looking for something on the lines of `dateto = dateto[5..8] + dateto[0..1] + dateto[2..3]`
. Not sure how to write that in JS though.

Comment: Look at the `split` method instead.

Comment: I'd construct a new date object by parsing it: (new Date(Date.parse("05/01/2013"))) ... then you can just get at the pieces. But, as you can see, there are many ways to go about this. Most of these answers never bother converting to a date object and just use string manipulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use some simple string maniuplation

```
var dateto = "05/01/2013";
var parts = dateto.split('/');
var newDate = parts[2] + parts[0] + parts[1];
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kvU6H/

Comment: I'd argue regex is the simplest solution. Don't have to create a new variable for it

Comment: @JoeFrambach I would agree as well, but I would also argue not everyone is well versed in regular expressions :P

Comment: It's not exactly rocket science

Comment: Very true, but I have some coworkers that think otherwise unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression and capture groups:

```
"05/01/2013".replace(
    /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, // capture data in groups
    "$3$1$2")                    // replace with captured groups
```

While the above approach works well enough for this specific case, consider a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
moment
    .parse("05/01/2013", "MM/DD/YYY") // parse our format
    .format("YYYYMMDD")               // write target format
```

Comment: should be `$3$1$2` (YYYYMMDD)

Comment: "05/01/2013".replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/,'$3$1$2') is enough.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I considered using the + quantifier but rejected it because "5/1/2013" would then result in "201351". I would rather have the process fail in a more obvious manner - although one could argue that the approaches above still don't fail hard/soon enough.

Answer (score -1):

You could consider the [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function where you just provide the beginning and end positions (or *indexes*) of the desired string in the original string:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var dateto = "05/01/2013";

    return dateto.substring(6, 10) + dateto.substring(0, 2) + dateto.substring(3, 5);
}
```

returns:

```
20130501
```

Indexes start from 0 in Javascript (and most programming languages)... so for your string:

```
string:  0  5  /  0  1  /  2  0  1  3  
 index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```